# Is it a good idea to combine the ideas of version 1 and version 4 UUIDs?

Tags: java, database, random, uuid, uniqueidentifier

I want to generate time-based UUIDs, but I don't want any part of the UUID value to be based on the machine they are generated on.

Version 1 UUIDs are time-based (with the first 64 bits representing time, and the second 64 bits representing the MAC address of the machine they are generated on).

Version 4 UUIDs are not time-based, but are generated from random numbers.

In my case, I want to be able to generate multiple time-based UUIDs for the same timestamp, on the same machine - and I want those UUIDs to be unique. The UUIDs must still be time-based, so that sorting them lexicographically gives an ordering consistent with the timestamps used to create them.

Is there any good reason not to generate UUIDs with my own scheme - where the first 64 bits would represent the timestamp (like version 1) and the second 64 bits would be randomly generated (like version 4)?

Comment: You need to reverse the question: is there any reason why you **shouldn't** just use version 4 UUIDs?

Comment: I don't want to use version 4 UUIDs because I want to be able to sort a list of UUIDs and get them in order of the timestamps used to create them

Comment: Sorting UUIDs? You are using the wrong tool for the job. You shouldn't care about lexical ordering of UUIDs at all.

Comment: Now, that is an entirely different ball game. :) You can of course do that then, but the likelihood of collisions is going to be a lot higher. Not so much accidental collisions, but collisions where someone tries to guess a valid, already generated id. Whether that's a problem for your system or not, I don't know. Either way, I would definitely choose to store the timestamp alongside the guid and not as part of it.

Comment: You are probably right that it isn't the correct way to sort things by time. But imagine you have a database table which you insert records to and want to later retrieve in time order (in my case, this is in AWS where you pay for anything that takes space, including each index). If you have a separate timestamp column, you need a separate index, leading to more cost and slower retrieval time (unless the whole table is duplicated in that extra index - in which case double the cost). I was hoping to achieve faster lookups and lower costs with time-based UUIDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ULIDs](https://github.com/ulid/spec) meet your requirements pretty much exactly. You may need to generate them application-side since it looks like native database support seems lacking, but it's a drop-in for a 128bit UUID so you simply need to encode it as hex to insert into any UUID type column.

Answer (score 1):

If space isn't a concern you can combine the multithreaded/multi-machine collision resistance of a UUID with the lexical ordering of a timestamp:

```
System.currentTimeMillis() + "-" + UUID.randomUUID()
```